# How to save uuid from pyspark dataframe to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, uuid

```
Getting the below error while saving uuid to postgresql 

at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(PgStatement.java:2356)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:395)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1912)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:338)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:2534)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:838)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:838)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:980)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 276
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
... 17 more

Comment: Having the same issue :/  but, got another error message: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying

Comment: @user1809802 did you find a solution other than changing the datatype in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly spark seems to implicitly cast uuid type to varying character when it loads data into a dataframe. I'm still looking for an optimal way of doing this, but as of now it seems that using triggers to re-cast fields as uuid is the most secure way to get uuid where it should belong. Beware that this kind of approach creates overhead and should be benchmarked to see if it's worth. I'd suggest to drop the use of uuid in favor of integer ids since the uuid type has [some performance issues](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/) and is not fully cross-database compatible.